# Handling Bitmask Type in Doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine-query

I have a bitmask type which stores various flags.

I am having problem in executing the following query using doctrine.

```
SELECT id, name, flags FROM stores WHERE flags & 4 = 4;
```

I have tried the following code but I get the error saying `[Syntax Error] line 0, col 175: Error: Expected =, <, <=, <>, >, >=, !=, got '&'`.

**METHOD 1:**

```
$builder = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();
$builder->select('ads')
        ->from($this->getClassName(), 'ads')
        ->where("ads.flags & 4=4");
return new ArrayCollection($builder->getQuery()->getResult());
```

------------------ OR -------------------

**METHOD 2:**

```
$repo->findBy(['flags' => '& 4=4']);
```

How to successfully implement the mentioned raw SQL query using the first and second method?

Comment: What's the reason for using "& 4 = 4"?